# Remove and merge duplicate records in a CSV file

Tags: ruby, csv, duplicates

The data set has duplicate records. There can be more than one
duplicate for the same contact.

How do I remove duplicate records, and build a single record for each
name with maximum possible fields.

Sample input file:

```
FN,    LN,    phone1,      phone2,       email,        city  
Matt,  x,     9800000000,            ,              ,  NYC  
Matt,   ,     9800000001,  8822334490,              ,  
Matt,  x,     9845012345,  9800000000,              ,  
Matt,   ,     9800000000,            , xyz@gmail.com,  NYC  
Matt,  x,               ,  9845012345, xyz@gmail.com,  NYC  
Matt,  x,     9845012345,  9800000000,              ,  NYC  
Matt,  y,     9800000001,            ,              ,  NYC  
kyle,  z,     8759235755,            ,              ,  NJ
```

Sample Output:

```
FN,    LN,  phone1,      phone2,    email,         city  
Matt,   x,  9800000000, 9845012345, xyz@gmail.com, NYC  
Matt,   y,  9800000001, 8822334490,              , NYC  
kyle,   z,  8759235755,           ,              , NJ
```

Comment: Is there actually whitespace between the fields, or did you add it for clarity? Also, the rules for constructing the merged records are unclear - you said "a single record for each name", but there are two "Matt"s, and `Matt,y`'s combined record has content that doesn't exist for him in the sample input.

Comment: @TimPietzcker: I've added whitespaces for empty fields for clarity. first_name is a mandatory field and rest all are optional fields and also there can be more than one duplicate also for the same contact.

Comment: What do you account as duplicate record, only FN, and phone1, or a whole line?

Comment: Can guys re-open it, I do have an answer for this.. Please vote for re-opening..

Answer (score 0):

Have looked at the find_or_create_by

The find_or_create_by method checks whether a record with the attributes exists. If it doesn't, then create is called. Let's see an example.

Suppose you want to find a client named 'Andy', and if there's none, create one. You can do so by running:

```
Client.find_or_create_by(first_name: 'Andy')
# => #<Client id: 1, first_name: "Andy", orders_count: 0, locked: true, created_at: "2011-08-30 06:09:27", updated_at: "2011-08-30 06:09:27">
```

---

Comment: This method is available in `ActiveRecord` I do not see the issue Rails.